# Isotope: Getting an AJAX Load More button to load more posts in the same Masonry format

Tags: jquery, wordpress, masonry, jquery-isotope

Having a lot of issues trying to get an AJAX based Load More Posts button to work where it adds additional posts but the post grid is in a Masonry format. I added the Easy Load More plugin for WordPress and it works, but instead of the posts loading the new posts in a Masonry format, instead all the posts appear in the left most column and the posts crash into the footer, basically making a mess of things. Any idea why the new posts aren't appearing as masonry?

Here's an example:
https://starmountaincapital.com/category/twitter/

the main container is called .grid and each item is wrapped in a grid-item div

Comment: which plugin are you using

Comment: Please checkout this plugins `https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/`

Comment: I'm using Easy Load More. I tried ALM but it just made a complete mess of my masonry / isotope layout.